# Right spring config for added project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I had got a working spring-hibernate project and i decided to move part of this project to a new one, to have something like base project. 
This new base project contents some dao classes for hibernate and a lot of spring annotations. So I sucessfully created it and released it to my repository. After that I added it like dependency to my first project. Also I added to spring config  with packages of base project. 
Now I have base project with no spring/hibernate config. And another project that depends of base one, and this another project has spring/hibernate config.

And now I recieve a lot of runtime errors. 
1. My service class in base project can not autowire DAO class from another package in base project. After I put it in one package problem was sloved. But I dont like it much.
2. My DAO methods falls in runtime with "No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here". But previously, when I had one project they worked fine.

Do I need a spring configs in base project? And how can I do such things right?

**Update**

Now problem in spring transaction manager.
In base project i've got base abstract controller with dao classes. In main class I've got controller that inherits base contoller. When I run project on server I recieve "No Hibernate Session bound to thread" when base dao call sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().
But before I splited this projects everything works great. And if I run Dao methods from junit they also work fine.

**Slove**
Problem was that some packages was added in "context:component-scan" twise. And it gives this effect.
Thanks guys for your replys.

Answer (score 0):

If you use @Service or @Component annotations for your dao/services in main project (not base one) you need to specify scan packages in spring context xml. This should work.

The same thing can be done with hibernate entities mapping. In main project use Spring LocalSessionFactoryBean to set hibernate entities scan packages from base project. This also should work for you as it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Spring configs files can be everywhere in the classpath (base project, main project...). You just need to add them to the context in the Web.xml file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:/applicationContext-context1.xml         
        classpath:/applicationContext-context2.xml
        classpath:/applicationContext-context3.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-context4.xml 
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

I think it is better you have all of them in your main application (not in base library) as you are doing now.